# rails, allow exception in route globbing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, glob

i was wondering if i could add an exception to route globbing in rails. in my routes.rb i have

```
    unless params[:not_found].eql? 'admin_data'
         match '*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404'
    end
```

im trying to enforce custom error pages, except when a user visits

```
myapp.heroku.com/admin_data
```

it doesn't seem like fetching :not_found as a param works. is there a way to add an exception in routes.rb?

if it helps, in my errors_controller i have..

```
  def error_404
        @not_found_path = params[:not_found]
  end
```

thank you

**update**.

i tried doing just

```
puts :not_found
puts %{not_found}
```

but doesn't seem to work either hmmm...im trying to see if i can retrieve the params from the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much more convenient to define allowed routes in routes.rb and add exception handling in application controller for routing error:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_not_found

  private
    def render_not_found 
      render_error_page_for(404)
    end

    def render_error_page_for(code)
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/#{code}.html", :status => code, :layout => false }
    end
end
```

Comment: i fixed it with my answer below. thank you for responding though! i appreciate you answering and shall accept!

Answer (score 0):

i do catch my exception handling in my application controller but unfortunately for admin_data, i don't explicitly set it in routes.rb. it gets configured somewhere in the gem with namespace or something (im not really sure)

but on a positive note... i finally fixed it! i changed my glob and did...

```
match '*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404', :constraints => {:subdomain => "!(admin_data.)"}
```

to ignore everything which uses admin_data.

Comment: this is causing me problems when I try to access files that are under public folder, it's a nice solution though.